# What am I? You all need me

Tags: riddle

> My prefix is for businesses and everyone else.
>
> My infix is what you do with a Greek (or Medieval) sphere.
>
> My suffix is a clue I don't remember.
>
> Everyone here needs me.

What am I?

Comment: Aaaaah, @Riley, what have you done!!!!

Comment: @rhsquared idk man everyone just started copying the format of that riddle but I'm not complaining :)

Comment: This format is fun to make and fun to answer :)

Comment: If nobody gets it by 11 PM (EDT)-ish, I'll post a hint.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this might be...

> **Computer**

*My prefix is for businesses and everyone else*

> The **.com** domain, which was first for commercial organizations then open for everyone else.

*My infix is what you do with a Greek (or Medieval) sphere*

> To **put**, as in the Olympic sport of [shot put](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_put).

*My suffix is a clue I don't remember*

> **Er...** What was that hint again? ;)

*Everyone here needs me*:

> Sad but true, though a portable device might also suffice. :)

Comment: This is the correct answer! Good job.